# Wireplumber doesn't see my sound card

Tags: pulseaudio, wireplumber

My current audio stack is `wireplumber`, `pipewire`, `pipewire-pulse`, `alsa`. I had three sound devices on my machine, a USB microphone, a USB webcam, and my desktop's integrated sound ports, and an HDMI port.

Today, I plugged a headphone set into the front I/O panel of my desktop and my sound card disappeared as pulse audio sink.  It no longer appears as a sink in `pavucontrol`.  I have restarted all the appropriate services and even the system several times.  The audio card never returns. Yes, I have unplugged the headphones.  Wireplumber is currently trying to play audio out of my USB mic.

- `alsamixer` is able to see all the audio devices although I can't enable it.
- `pactl list cards` can see all the audio cards
- `pactl list sinks` only lists my USB microphone.

Answer (score 1):

After doing many things such as uninstalling wireplumber and pipewire, unplugging my input devices, and attempting [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344880/microphone-not-showing-up-as-input-device-in-settings-only-in-pavucontrol), I found that my card had been *unconfigured*.  I saw it as listed with no profile under the "Configuration" tab of `pavucontrol`.  Setting a configuration immediately turned it back on.

I tried plugging the headphones in again and it broke again.  It seems like pulseaudio will automatically change the profile of the card and mute it any outputs whenever I plug or unplug any device to the desktop IO.  I also found that when I did restore the sound through `pavucontrol` the profile would be listed as "(unavailable)" and sound would only come from the left side.  Running the appropriate `pactl load-module` command from the solution above would restore it immediately.